# Parametrize query in RPostgres and append results in a new dataframe

Tags: r, tidyverse, rpostgresql

I have a set of pair values stored in a dataframe `parameters`:

```
parameters <- data.frame(
   variant_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
   start_date = c("2019-07-01", "2019-09-05", "2019-05-21", "2019-09-06",
                  "2019-04-19"))

> parameters
  variant_id start_date
1          1 2019-07-01
2          2 2019-09-05
3          3 2019-05-21
4          4 2019-09-06
5          5 2019-04-19
```

I want to use this combinations of `variant_id` and `start_date` as dynamic parameters in this SQL query performed in RPostgres.

```
library(RPostgres)
library(tidyverse)

query <- "select sum(o.quantity)
from orders o
where o.date >= << start_date >>
and o.variant_id = << variant_id >> "

df <- dbGetQuery(db, query)
```

I will have then queries like:

```
query_1 <- "select sum(o.quantity)
from orders o
where o.date >= '2019-07-01'
and o.variant_id = 1 "

result_1 <- dbGetQuery(db, query_1)
 > result_1
     sum
   1 100

query_2 <- "select sum(o.quantity)
from orders o
where o.date >= '2019-09-05'
and o.variant_id = 2 "

result_2 <- dbGetQuery(db, query_2)
 > result_2
     sum
   1 120


query_3 <- "select sum(o.quantity)
from orders o
where o.date >= '2019-05-21'
and o.variant_id = 3 "

result_3 <- dbGetQuery(db, query_3)
 > result_3
     sum
   1 140
```

... and so on.

Then, I would like to append each result in a new dataframe `results` as:

```
results <- data.frame(
              variant_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                quantity = c(100, 120, 140, 150, 160)
           )

> results
  variant_id quantity
1          1      100
2          2      120
3          3      140
4          4      150
5          5      160
```

How can I approach this problem using `RPostgres` and `dplyr` avoiding the use of a loop?

Comment: Use `map` from `purrr` and `paste`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't have your database but have used `parameters` and `orders` given in the Note at the end.  We have added `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to the `parameters` definition to ensure that we have character strings.

Now, use `sprintf` to create a character vector of queries.  Then run each one.  Here we use `sqldf` to make everything reproducible since we don't have your data base but you can replace `sqldf` with the appropriate statement to get the result from your database.

```
query <- "select sum(o.quantity)
  from orders o
  where o.date >= '%s'
  and o.variant_id = %s "

queries <- with(parameters, sprintf(query, start_date, variant_id))

library(sqldf)

# replace sqldf in next line with appropriate function to invoke query
do.call("rbind", lapply(queries, sqldf))
##   sum(o.quantity)
## 1               1
## 2              NA
## 3               3
## 4              NA
## 5              NA
```

### Note

```
# test data

parameters <- data.frame(
   variant_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
   start_date = c("2019-07-01", "2019-09-05", "2019-05-21", "2019-09-06",
                  "2019-04-19"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

orders <- data.frame(date = "2019-07-02", variant_id = 1:3, quantity = 1:3)
```

Comment: I managed to generate the queries using the pairs of  `variant_id` and `start_date` correcty; how can I feed them into `dbGetQuery()` iteratively in order to append each result into a single dataframe? if I save `unname(sapply(split(parameters, 1:nr), with, fn$c(query)))` into an object, I get a character vector. Thanks!

Comment: I assume I can use `map()`. What I try to do is to apply `map(queries, dbGetQuery(db))` but I get: `Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbGetQuery’ for signature ‘"PqConnection", "missing"’`

Comment: It would be easier to do it in the way explained in the answer but if you want to do it that way use: `lapply(queries, function(stmt) dbQuery(connection, stmt))` or use `sapply`.

Comment: Since you seem to want to iterate over the queries even though it would not have been needed in the original answer I have revised the answer to produces `queries` directly using `sprintf`.